# Is it bad practice to have an empty class as a base class, with the expectation that the class may have members in the future?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

Simple example:

```
public class Food
{
    public virtual void Eat()
    {
        StuffInMouth();
    }
}

public class Fruit : Food
{
    // Nothing here yet, but likely could be in the future
    // Is this bad from a .NET/C# style guidelines perspective?
}

public class Apple : Fruit
{
    public virtual void Eat()
    {
        Clean();
        base.Eat();
    }
}

public class Orange : Fruit
{
    public virtual void Eat()
    {
        Peel();
        base.Eat();
    }
}
```

Comment: That can make sense. Changing the class hierarchy after the fact can be a breaking change to depending code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As simple as I can put it, it is called *[Speculative Generality](https://refactoring.guru/smells/speculative-generality).*

**Reasons for the Problem:** Sometimes code is created "just in case" to support anticipated future features that never get implemented. As a result, code becomes hard to understand and support.

---

<sub>*As Steve McConnell points out in Code Complete - 2,*</sub>

> <sub>*Programmers are notoriously bad at guessing what functionality might be needed someday.*</sub>

<sub>***1. Requirements aren't known, so programmer must guess:** Wrong guesses will mean the code must be thrown away.*</sub>

<sub>***2. Even a close guess will be wrong about the details:** These intricacies will undermine the programmer's assumptions - the code must be (or should be) thrown away.*</sub>

<sub>***3. Other/future programmers may assume the speculative code works better or is more necessary than it is:** They build code on the foundation of speculative code, adding to the cost when the speculative code must be removed or changed.*</sub>

<sub>***4. The speculative generality adds complexity and requires more testing and maintenance:** This adds to the cost and slows down the entire project.*</sub>

---

<sup>Credits: Code Complete - 2 | [Pluralsight course on refactoring](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/refactoring-fundamentals/table-of-contents).</sup>

Comment: @Rollie: Just to explain the point further... you have nothing in `Fruit` class because your code doesn't need to know whether Apple and Okra are `Fruit` or `Vegetable`. Adding class for `Fruit` would now become unused code which you need to maintain and for which you will have to maintain unit-tests etc too. Better to test and add the classes when you need instead of adding and maintaining them in hope of future need.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain.

Comment: I see the point, though my feeling is this is really case-by-case. Trivial example aside, imagine this same scenario, but with a much larger inheritance hierarchy/project. Lots of methods etc throughout a larger codebase accept a Food object, but really they only care about Fruit. Without this class (or an equally empty interface), they would have to accept a Food argument. However, as expressed, it is very likely there *will* be functionality in fruit, at which time all those locations should be updated.  If it's not needed, it's a small sacrifice for a big gain if it is needed.

Comment: @Rollie: Not just this, every step of programming and software designing is case by case. In your particular case, it doesn't matter how large inheritance hierarchy is, what matters is if it applicable or not. Is it important for the methods accepting apple and okra and orange to differentiate whether these three are fruits or vegetables? If yes, create the parent class (or interface) and help the methods. Otherwise, you probably just need a better name - something like `Eatables` which have the method `Eat()`. Contd...

Comment: @Rollie: ...Contd... Further, whether the sacrifice is small or big should be decided by looking at every aspect that this small change affects. You may have a confused developer who will look through entire code to understand why did the original code writer made this distinction and he will find that it wasn't needed. Then he was 2 more people about it and take their time even though his guess (that this distinction wasn't needed) is already correct. Further this code will require maintenance and will need you to update your tests when this wasn't needed at all in the first place.

Comment: @Rollie: Also, sometimes when you refactor the code properly after it has been written, you get an empty super/sub class. This class is finally removed in the end. It will probably happen to you too if you will keep this class without any need. You will refactor your code and in the end delete this class as it'd be serving no purpose in the shipped code.

Comment: @Rollie: See http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/inlineClass.html and http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html . This highlights the importance of writing only that code which matters.

Comment: This makes sense; in this case, i stipulated that it was *likely* there would be use for the intermediary class, so in the expectation is it would save less confusion than it causes. 

The actual impetus for this question is a good example of why (I think) it's good to design your hierarchy based on what makes conceptual sense, vs what has functionality.  This change was eventually abandoned; the code is in dire need of refactor, but in an ultra conservative development environment, such changes are difficult to push through. Had it been designed well at the start though...

Answer (score 2):

No one said a class must have any members. A class represents a category of objects, so in case they have no useful properties (not in the language's meaning) it's perfectly fine to have it empty. So what's important is whether the class does represent a meaningful category of objects your code needs to work with or not.

In your case, should your code generally operate on food, having a common `Food` ancestor makes sense. *However*, a better concept may be introducing an `IFood` interface, effectively **decoupling the food contract from actual inheritance hierarchies**. For example, a meaningful hierarchy may start with an `Animal` class, but not every animal is considered food (disclaimer: this is rough example).

Answer (score 1):

Imho It is an extra abstraction layer with no added value.
It adds unnecessary complexity, so in my opinion it's bad practice and an example of YAGNI.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, it is important to realize that while it can save time to do things like this (if it is used) it is typically better to code for the immediate future, or at least understand when you are coding for the future that will never come.

There is also maintenance overhead of implementing things too early.